# Qual o correto: não decrescente ou não-decrescente

Tags: português-brasileiro, hífen

Me deparo sempre com o termo: não-decrescente nos livros de matemática, porém me pergunto se o correto não é: não decrescente.

Comment: quando foram escritos os livros? Pode ser versão anterior da gramática.

Comment: Tem versões de 2013 e 2014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antes do novo acordo ortográfico era possível escrever: *não-decrescente*, *não-agressão*, *não-verbal*, todavia, em nota explicativa, a comissão de lexicologia e lexicografia da Academia Brasileira de Letras definiu, na 5ª edição do Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa — VOLP, que se deve:

> *15) Excluir o emprego do hífen nos casos em que as palavras **não** e **quase**
>   funcionam como prefixos: não agressão, não fumante, quase delito, quase irmão.* (Grifo meu)

Portanto o correto é:

> Não Agressão
>   Não Verbal
>   Não Decrescente

***Referências***

<sup>ACADEMIA BRASILEIRA DE LETRAS. **Nota explicativa da comissão de lexicologia e lexicografia da abl sobre os procedimentos metodológicos seguidos na elaboração da 5ª edição do volp em consonância com o que dispõe o novo acordo ortográfico da língua portuguesa e a nota explicativa que lhe serve de adendo como anexo ii, aprovado em lisboa em 1990.** [S. l.], 2009. Disponível em: http://www.academia.org.br/abl/media/Nota%20Explicativa%2009%2003%202008.pdf. Acesso em: 6 maio 2019.</sup>

Comment: Resposta simples e bem clara.